# R - "Error in varying[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions" when reshaping from long to wide

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape my dataframe from long to wide using the reshape() function in R. I was able to convert from wide to long with another dataset using [these instructions from R bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-dataset-from-wide-to-long/), but when using the same guidelines going the other way around I keep getting this error that I don't understand:

```
Error in varying[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Here is a sample of my data (PYS_shorter):

```
id_s phase  A   B       C       D       E       F
1    1      3   1.83    1.35    0.00    0.38    0.67
1    2      2   1.67    1.65    0.00    0.38    0.67
1    3      2   1.67    1.47    0.00    0.15    0.17
1    4      1   1.33    1.59    0.00    0.00    0.00
1    5      1   1.17    1.35    0.38    0.62    1.33
1    6      1   1.00    1.53    0.13    0.08    1.17
1    7      1   1.50    1.29    0.00    0.00    0.33
1    8      1   1.33    1.29    0.00    0.00    0.17
2    1      2   1.50    1.41    0.00    0.00    0.67
2    2      1   1.83    1.35    0.25    0.54    0.83
2    3      1   1.50    1.65    0.00    0.15    1.33
2    4      2   1.83    1.65    0.00    0.00    0.33
2    5      1   1.50    1.41    0.00    0.00    0.17
2    6      1   1.83    1.18    0.00    0.00    0.00
2    7      1   1.17    1.47    0.00    0.00    0.00
2    8      1   1.50    1.76    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Here is my code:

```
PYS_WIDE <- reshape(PYS_shorter, 
                varying = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                timevar = "phase", 
                idvar = "id_s", 
                direction="wide", 
                sep ="_")
```

What am I doing wrong? What does the error mean? How can I solve this, so I can reshape this dataframe from long to wide (so having 8 A variables, 8 B variables, etcetera and just one row per subject)?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Try excluding the `varying` argument.

Comment: Thanks @markus, that indeed works. But why?

Comment: Glad it worked. The arguments of the `reshape` function - albeit very powerful - remain a mystical to me. I took me a few tries till I found out.

Answer (score 0):

Try `spread` from `tidyr`. I think this is what you need.

```
df <- data.frame(id_s = c(1:26), phase = c(letters), A = c(100:125), B = c(1000:1025))

library(tidyr)
# wide to long
df %>%
  gather(data = ., key = Group_type, value = Value, -id_s, -phase ) -> long


# long to wide
long %>%
  spread(data = ., key = Group_type, value = Value)


head(long)
  id_s phase Group_type Value
1    1     a          A   100
2    2     b          A   101
3    3     c          A   102
4    4     d          A   103
5    5     e          A   104
6    6     f          A   105

head(wide)
  id_s phase   A    B
1    1     a 100 1000
2    2     b 101 1001
3    3     c 102 1002
4    4     d 103 1003
5    5     e 104 1004
6    6     f 105 1005
```

Comment: here is a useful link - http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Comment: that also discusses reshape()

Answer (score 0):

dput(Your_Data)

idvar
Names of one or more variables in long format that identify multiple records from the same group/individual. These variables may also be present in wide format.

Basically id_s is screwing your query, reshape doesn't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
varying = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
```

works, although I don't know why!